# How to display a specific XML node attribute?

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I want to create a simple "news" widget on my website linked to the RSS feed of my Squarespace blog.

The RSS feed can be found here : https://weboxsite.squarespace.com/?format=rss

When I load the XML data from my CURL function, I am unable to see some of the nodes when I print_r() my XML file.

Most particularly, I want to get the node attributes `<media>`.

When it comes to get the attributes of my `<media>` node, I am unable to get the url attribute.

I have simplified the result from the web for a simpler reading.

```
<item>
<title>Google Disque : un outil indispensable</title>
<category>Google drive</category>
<dc:creator></dc:creator>
<pubDate>Wed, 22 Jun 2016 21:25:37 +0000</pubDate>
<link>
http://blogue.webox.site/touslesarticles/2016/6/22/google-disque-un-outil-indispensable
</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">
5769a85b9de4bbf4535c1896:5769a8f1bebafb833a859939:576b01e48419c2d2589b7264
</guid>
<description>
My excerpt....
</description>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p>My content....</p> 
]]>
</content:encoded>
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5769a85b9de4bbf4535c1896/5769a8f1bebafb833a859939/576b01e48419c2d2589b7264/1466630737869/1500w/googledisque_bg.jpg" medium="image" isDefault="true" width="510" height="334">
<media:title type="plain">Google Disque : un outil indispensable</media:title>
</media:content>
</item>
```

** The main problem **

```
<media:content type="image/jpeg" url="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5769a85b9de4bbf4535c1896/5769a8f1bebafb833a859939/576b01e48419c2d2589b7264/1466630737869/1500w/googledisque_bg.jpg" medium="image" isDefault="true" width="510" height="334">
    <media:title type="plain">Google Disque : un outil indispensable</media:title>
    </media:content>
```

**Here is my code so far**

```
<?php 
$limit = 4;

    $c=curl_init('https://weboxsite.squarespace.com/?format=rss');

    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'nesss' );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $r=curl_exec( $c );
    curl_close( $c );

    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->loadxml($r);

    $feed = array();

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {

        $item = array ( 
            'title'     =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link'      =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'media'     =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('media')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'cat'       =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('category')->item(0)->nodeValue
        );

        array_push($feed, $item);
    }

    for($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {

        $title  = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link   = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $desc   = $feed[$x]['media'];
        $cat   = $feed[$x]['cat'];

        echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong></p>';
        echo '<p>'.$cat.'</p>';

    }

    ?>
```

I know that doing this `'media' =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('media')->item(0)->nodeValue` is not the good way to do it as it tries to render the value.

I tried to place `'media'=>  $node->getElementsByTagName('media')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')` but I am getting an error.

```
Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in ...
```

I might think it is because the node is named media:content and not only media, but event with this changed, it goes no where.

Do I have something missing somewhere?

Comment: Could you be more specific as I almost tried everything I am able to do with my experience ?

Comment: Forget my last comment. I thing is a problem with the used NAMESPACES in the XML `media` and `content` and `dc`. Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
getElementsByTagNameNS ( string $namespaceURI , string $localName )
```

Here the namespaceURI's from your file:

xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"

xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"

xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"

xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

xmlns:media="http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss"

so finally:

`'media' =>  $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue`

becomes

`'media' =>  $node->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss','content')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')`

Keep in mind :  "NAMESPACE:NODENAME" , so you are looking for `content` not `media`

Hope that helps.

Comment: With the new line of code that you gave me, I have this. 

[0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Google Disque : un outil indispensable
            [link] => http://blogue.webox.site/touslesarticles/2016/6/22/google-disque-un-outil-indispensable
            [media] => Google Disque : un outil indispensable
            [cat] => Google drive
        )

Looks like it returns the value of the media title (<media:title type="plain">Google Disque : un outil indispensable</media:title>) instead of the URL attribute value.

Comment: Or better test a little bit, my focus here was to tell you about Namespaces in XML. Rest is on you.

Comment: XML are little tricky, go read the next answer from ThW way better than mine.

Comment: Thank you, I will give a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

The elements with `media:` are in a different XML namespace. Because you're reading RSS that should be Media-RSS. Look for the attribute `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"`. This is the definition for the namespace. The parser resolves the prefix to the actual namespace.

- `media:content` -> `{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}content`
- `media:title` -> `{http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/}title`

Because the element is in a namespace, you will have to use the namespace aware methods:

```
$title = $node->getElementsByTagNameNS(
  'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/', 'title'
)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Or you use Xpath expression and register your own prefix.

```
$rss = new DOMDocument();
$rss->loadxml($r);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($rss);
$xpath->registerNamespace('m', 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

$feed = array();
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $node) {
    $feed[] = array( 
        'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $node),
        'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $node),
        'media-title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(m:content/m:title)', $node),
        'cat' => $xpath->evaluate('string(category)', $node)
    );
}
```